# Heroku app module not found error with pickle module in python I believe

Tags: python, heroku, pickle

The app runs fine on local but when pushed to heroku I am getting a module not found error surrounding my pickle load.  I tried to add the missing module to the requirements.txt but received more errors.  Below is the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.serialize'
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/app.py", line 49, in <module>
    UMAP = pickle.load((open('data/UMAPwrv.sav', 'rb')))
```

Does anyone know how to remedy this? Thanks!

Comment: Freeze your requirements and include in your repository. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to start using venv for managing Python packages. You can know more about it [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

However, as the documentation clearly states:

> These are the lowest-level tools for managing Python packages and are recommended if higher-level tools do not suit your needs.

So, my personal recommendation is using [Pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile).